# Python docx file converted to exe using py2exe, cmd prompt opened and closed immediately

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe, python-docx

I am converting the py file to exe file

The below code is user for conversion and it is very simple

```
import docx
print "Hai"
p = raw_input()
```

My "setup.py" file has the following code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
console=['Sample.py']
)
```

"Sample.exe" file generated successfully, but when i open the "Sample.exe", cmd prompt opens and closed immediately

I have also added following code in "setup.py", but it didn't work out

```
data_files = 
[('docx/template', ['C:/Python27/Lib/site-
packages/docx/templates/*'])],
```

Can any one help me on this

Comment: Try using pyinstaller. It is more user friendly.

Comment: @trishant-pahwa: Thanks, it works for me, i am able to generate the exe using pyinstaller using the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11Q2QADsAEE